# Force FormattedNumber in react-intl to show only english number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intl

I'm working on a react app that needs to be localized in English and Arabic, when switching from English to Arabic all the numbers are switching to Arabic also which in my case should remain in English format.

is there a way that i can override the `Locales` in `IntlProvider` and force to use only `en-US` locale?

Comment: What do you mean by english numbers? It's `123` in both languages isn't it?

Comment: yes, i need the numbers to remain in English format like 123 or 123.4. but in my case they are switching to Arabic numbers format

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to this problem. By wrapping the `FormattedNumber` component by `IntlProvider` and passing `locale='en'` as props to `Intlprovider` i was able to override the App `locales`.

Comment: You can use .toLocaleString('en-US') if you have few numbers